# Selecting a Range while looping through worksheets in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've shortened my code a bit for the purposes of the question, but the error I'm getting is the same.

When trying to select the cells with data in column A on each worksheet and doing stuff with it, I get an error after the first worksheet:

```
Sub quickSub()

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Worksheets
    sh.Range("A6", Range("A6").End(xlDown)).Select

''Random bits of code here where I manipulate selection on each worksheet

Next

End Sub
```

The error I get is:

```
"Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sh.Activate
sh.Range("A6", "A" & sh.Range("A6").End(xlDown).row).Select
```

I made sure the range reference was end downing on the right sheet
And I had the end down return the final row number and concatenate with the column letter which may not be needed, but may make it easier for you to debug.

**Update:**

Added activate line. Selection may require the sheet be active.

**Update2:**

Here's the 'Right' way to do this WITHOUT using select 
Using this method directly referneces the worksheet data INSTEAD of needing to move around worksheet by worksheet.
This best practice will increase your code performance

```
Sub quickSub()

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Worksheets
    With sh.Range("A6", "A" & sh.Range("A6").End(xlDown).row)
        '- lines that manipulate the 'selection' in the above with
        .Value = "NewValue"
        .font.bold = true


    End With

''Random bits of code here where I manipulate selection on each worksheet

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! when I use that, roughly the same thing happens, except the error is now:

    "Run-time error '1004':
    
    Select method of Range class failed"

Comment: Updated answer. be sure you are activating a sheet before attempting to select it.

Comment: Welcome. I added a second answer that shows an alternative 'better' way to accomplish what you are trying to do. It may be irrelevant for a small example, but it is a best practice that is absolutely necessary when coding larger projects so it's best to start the habit to avoid using `Select` as soon as possible.

Comment: Will do! I'm relatively new to VBA/coding in general so any tips such as these are definitely helpful. Thanks again!